# Goat grazing area in an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

Q. A goat is tied to the vertex of an equilateral triangle shaped grass field with a rope of 25m . Over what area of the grass field can the goat graze ?

Isn't this statement wrong 
Or can we solve this question with this statement assuming the statement right ?

Comment: It depends on the size of the triangle, no?

Comment: I am also confused whether to take area of triangle or sector ?

Comment: Area of sector. Probably the side of the triangle is $> 25$ m, otherwise the goat grazes the whole field.

Comment: @user215312 If *you* don't know what the question is asking, then how can any of *us* help you?

Comment: I rewrited the statement here from the book i got this

Comment: How is this related to Algebraic Geometry? By the way you can get your answer as a function of the length of the rope.

Comment: I have replaced "Algebraic Geometry" by "Geometry". Algebraic geometry is a fully different subject as underlined by @Parish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle at the vertex of an equilateral triangle measures $60^\circ$. The goat cannot go outside of the field, presumably, and he cannot go farther than $25 \ \mathrm{m}$ away from the vertex.

Thus the grazable area is the sector of a circle of radius $25 \ \mathrm{m}$ and corresponds to the angle $60^\circ$.

Use the formula $$A=\frac{\theta}{360^\circ}\pi r^2$$ where $\theta$ is in degrees.

---

Nevertheless, you are right: the question is not specific enough. For all we know, the triangular field could measure only $1 \ \mathrm{m}$ on each side! That is definitely not a lot of area to graze!

Since the question does not specify the size of the field, we make an inference about what understanding it is testing, and we prove we have that understanding.

Comment: This is true as long as the median of the triangle is more than 25 m.  What if the median is less than that?  Again, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I discuss this in the final two paragraphs ;)

Comment: [+1] Thanks to your answer, with its last comment, I understand now the question...

Comment: @JeanMarie I am glad! I often had this problem when I was in middle school. A very gifted teacher of mine taught me to ask myself, “What does the grader want to see that I know, and what can I show him/her so that I get the maximum points?”